# How to create a GitHub issue from within R?

Tags: r, github

Is there a way to create a GitHub issue from within R? I had a look at the [GitHub API documentation](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/reference/issues#create-an-issue). There is an endpoint for creating issues but I'm not sure how to translate that into R code.

Comment: Maybe you can use that endpoint in the `gh` package: https://github.com/r-lib/gh#readme (I haven't tried).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your username is `user` and you have a repository called `my-repo`, then this code will create a new issue with the specified title and body text in the repo.

```r
gh::gh(
  endpoint = "POST /repos/user/my-repo/issues",
  title = "Issue title",
  body = "Some text"
)
```

In order for this to work you need a [GitHub access token](https://docs.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/creating-a-personal-access-token). Once you created one make sure to add it to `.Renviron`, e.g. using [`usethis::edit_r_environ()`](https://usethis.r-lib.org/reference/edit.html).

If you are using GitHub Enterpise then you will have to set the `.api_url` argument of `gh::gh()`.